# Is there opensource socks5 server for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, socks

I can not find any opensource Socks5 server for ubuntu, I need to use Socks5 server to proxy

client to access, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is google down again? I get lots of relevant links and software at http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=opensource+socks+server+linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can do socks5 if its compiled in

http://docstore.mik.ua/squid/FAQ-4.html#ss4.10

**EDIT**

Looks like ssh might be able to do it.. untested but checkout

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy

Comment: I think Squid can just proxy http request, right? i need to proxy most tcp/ip packets

Comment: no.. if you set it up as a socks5 proxy it will work just fine

Comment: i made an edit on how to use ssh as a socks5 proxy

Comment: If i use ssh, I do not know how to make all the request send by ssh in the windows client. I only know it can be set in firefox :)

Comment: @why, socks5 is not a VPN, support by the client is pretty much required.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I need one opensource socks5 client. such as SocksCap

Comment: This is not true from my understanding. Squid can *use* socks itsself if compiled in, but it provides a HTTP proxy. SS5 will provide a socks proxy. from http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Squid-as-a-SOCKS-Proxy-td1024095.html

Answer (score 6):

[ss5](http://ss5.sourceforge.net/) is a high-performance, dedicated SOCKS4, SOCKS4a and SOCKS5 proxy for Linux, Solaris and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

delegate
dante
3proxy
polipo
and more....

Comment: No, Polipo can act as a SOCKS client, not as a SOCKS proxy.